# Laravel: Using same id as the frontend

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, laravel

I'm using **React** and **Laravel** for the creation of a list.
My problem is that when a **element created**, in the database, receives an incremented `id` instead of the `id` provided in my front end.

Here is an image demonstrating the `id` in the console and the `id` in the database :

[image]

In the add button I have the following

```
 function handleAdd() {
    const newList = list.concat({ name, id: uuidv4(), value });
    setList(newList);
    setName("");
    setValue("");
  }

const onAddSocial = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

const test = {
  value: value,
  name: name,
};

axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/social', test)
  .then((res) => {
    toast(<div class="text-primary font-weight-bolder">Social link added successfully!</div>,{ delay: 0 });
    console.log(res)
  }).catch((error) => {console.log(error)
  })

}
```

And the button to trigger both functions for the creation :

```
 <Button                  
                onClick={(e) => {
                  props.handleAdd();
                  props.onAddSocial(e);
                }}
              >
```

The store controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = new Social();
    $data->value = $request->value;
    $data->name = $request->name;
    $data->save();
}
```

**How do I pass the `id` of the created element to the database, or perhaps how can the created element receives it `id` from the database after the creation.**

Comment: Your frontend should not control the id of the created model. You call the api, to create an model and the dom should be updated after that.

Comment: @mrhn I see. But when I want for example to delete an element, I'm passing in the delete function `id`, which takes the `id` of the frontend and search in the database, resulting in an error. Do you have an idea about how to proceed ?

Comment: sadly i'm not into react only vuejs mainly a backender. But basicly axiost.post().then((res) => list.add(res)) pseudo style. Don't create your models first and then save em.

Comment: @mrhn I think you gave me an idea to test. I will see what I can do now thank you.

Comment: as @mrhn said, you (mostly) never let the frontend share the ID you want to use to create it, if you want to use UUID, you can do so on the backend when you are creating the model in your controller, but you have to change your table primary key (`id`) to be non-incremental and use what you pass to it, in this case a `UUID`. You can also have both `id` and `uuid`, but remember to mark `uuid` as `unique` so it is sort of a primary key and also indexed.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I see. You are talking about changing the nature of the `id` to `uuid`, my problem is that when I'm editing or deleting an element, the axios request takes the `id ` of the database to delete the item, which contradict the `id` on the frontend, resulting in an error.

Comment: That is because you are creating an ID in your frontend instead of sharing the table's row ID.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Well yea. Since I can't create the element without ID in the frontend. Can I ? And what do you mean by sharing the table's ID ?

Comment: You are talking now about 2 different things, the code you are showing us (and the question) is about creating/storing the data. We told you that should let the backend select the ID, you don't have to send it to it, as that is a security risk. Once you have this sorted out, you can then see your data in another blade (or same) and when you press the `delete` button, you will already have the `id` as you got this data from the database itself, so the ID exists. Once you sort out this first problem, create a new question, as this second part will be off-topic.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Ah now that is clear for me. You are right, I have to sort this issue first. I have some ideas now, I just need to fetch the ID from the database rather that using UUID to assign a value for the id. Thank you.

Comment: Yes ! Once you have this running, create a new question, I would gladly help you there with that new idea.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I don't know if I didn't pay attention. But after refreshing the page, the `id`s are correct to the corresponding elements. And I can modify them or delete them. I guess the new list that axios get have the "good" ids but after refreshing the page. Is there any way to get the new list without refreshing the page ? In my `axios.get` I'm using a `useEffect` to get the list.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Haha well this is what I did and it worked ! After adding a new element, I told axios to load the new list, with the correct ids, and I was able to delete/edit. Thank you very very much man for the ideas.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out yourself !!! It is not difficult, it only requires perseverance ! And you did it !

Comment: @matiaslauriti And at what cost, heh ! Seriously I'm still learning but progress has been very slow. But I'm getting there.